# Laptop can't connect to many websites (ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT) from home WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome, router, firefox, mac-address

I'm having a pretty weird problem. At some point and without having done anything different, my laptop just can't connect to certain websites (many websites, not just 3 or 4). When I try to access those sites I get the following errors:

[Imgur album](https://imgur.com/a/krt8fam#3i9TOdX)

Firefox: Secure Connection Failed (no error code)
Opera: ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT
Chrome: ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT
Edge: ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT

Some info:

- The problem only happens when I am on Wi-Fi (on ethernet I can connect everywhere fine).
- The problem only happens when using my home Wi-Fi. I've connected to many other Wi-Fi's and everything works fine.
- Windows 11, Lenovo.
- Network adapter: Qualcomm Atheros Wireless Network Adapter.
- I'm not using an extender or signal booster.
- [EDIT:] Every other device in my network has no problems.

Things I've tried:

- Removing the laptop from the router's page manually (DIDN'T WORK)
- Restarting the router (DIDN'T WORK)
- Changing router (DIDN'T WORK)
- Several OS and browser settings (DIDN'T WORK)
- Uninstalled/Reinstalled network adapter drivers (DIDN'T WORK)
- Connecting via a [WiFi USB network adapter](https://www.repair-center.gr/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/TL-WN822N.jpg) (WORKED)
- Connecting via ethernet cable (WORKED)
- Connecting in other WiFi networks (WORKED)
- Connecting via VPN (WORKED)

So far I wasn't able to find any similarities or pattern between the several sites that I can't connect to. Here's a small list of some of the sites that I can't visit:

https://www.metal-archives.com/
https://randomgenerate.io/
https://www.random.org/
https://www.insomnia.gr/
https://downdetector.com/
https://torrentfreak.com/
https://www.thingiverse.com/

Comment: By "external antenna" do you mean a USB Wi-Fi network adapter, or do you mean literally an antenna somehow plugged into the Atheros Wi-Fi card?

Comment: @u1686_grawity a usb TP-link network adpater. I will edit to make it clearer

Comment: Do you have any third-party network adapter software installed? What is the MTU set to while connected to the wireless access point?

Comment: @Ramhound MTU is 1492. No third party software, no boosters. The router is the one I've always been using. No other device in my network has such a problem. The only difference is moving from win 10 to 11 and even then it's not that the moment I update to win 11 the laptop started behaving like this, but it's the only thing I can think of that happened between the current behaviour and the old (normal one).